# Excel formula to check if keyword exists in string and then match that keyword to another word

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got a table, which contains a column that contains text which is delimited by `_`.

The rates of `_` are inconsistent but there are specific keywords, that are usually the same.

For example, what I want is:

```
The Main table:

Column1  | Column2                     |Column3|   ...   |KeywordColumn
data     | some_word_keyword           |...    |         |Keyword
data     | some_other_keywordagain_word|...    |         |Keyword: again
...      | ...                         |...    |         |...
```

I created a helper table, which consists of 2 columns, one containing all the possible keywords I'm looking for, and one containing all keywords properly formatted.

E.G.

```
KeywordTable

Keywords      | Displayed Keywords            
keyword       | Keyword
keywordagain  | Keyword: again
...           | ...
```

What i got so far is this formula:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(FIND(LookupTable[Keywords],[@Column2]))>0),"found", "not found")
```

So what I got is:

```
The Main table:

Column1  | Column2                     |Column3|   ...   |KeywordColumn
data     | some_word_keyword           |...    |         |found
data     | some_other_keywordagain_word|...    |         |found
...      | ...                         |...    |         |...
```

Now I'm struggling with finding a way to reference the keyword, that triggered a True within that isnumber array and use that somehow.

TL;DR

I want to go from Column2 to KeywordColumn using a formula and KeywordTable

Comment: Sorry, but i'm not sure what the expected result is. Do you want a list of all the keywords in a sting?

Comment: the expected result is within the "KeywordColumn"

Comment: Note that `some_word_keyword` and `some_other_keywordagain_word` will return `Keyword` in both cases because both of them **contain** the string `keyword`

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns so far it doesnt even return that. all i got so far is "true", "false" on wether the full string even contains keyword or not

Answer (score 0):

if this is the desired result

[image]

the this would be the formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$8:$A$9,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$8:$A$9,$A1)),ROW($A$8:$A$9)-ROW($A$8)+1),COLUMN(A1))),"-")
```

Put this in `B1` und pull it downwards and sideways

Comment: can you explain what exactly the formula does/how it works?

Comment: `A1:A3` is your column 2 and `A8:A9` is the keyword list. The formula creates alist of all found kewords in a cell.